# Plotting date data on the x axis with datetime.datetime

Tags: python

I have the number of tweets containing a keyword on specific dates.  The data looks like

```
x=
...
'28/1/2015',
'02/2/2015',
'11/1/2015',
'27/1/2015',
...
```

The dates are in (MM/DD,YYYY).  I have another array `y` of the number of tweets on those days.

I would like to plot the number of tweets on each dat as a scatter plot.  I have been looking around and have seen that `datetime` can be used to do this, but have no experience with the package.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Sorry, `matplotlib.pyplot`

Comment: You might find this example [date_demo_convert.py](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/date_demo_convert.html) instructive.  The important part is the `DateFormatter`.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use parser. It can correctly infer the dates from strings in most cases.

```
from parser import parse

dates = []
for i in x:
   dates.append(parse(i))

plt.plot(dates, tweets)
plt.show()
```